# How do I turn off "IDE2001 Embedded statements must be on their own line" in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

This analyzer in Visual Studio annoys the heck out of me, "IDE2001 Embedded statements must be on their own line" even triggers on `while (true) { ... }`. How is `true` an embedded statement?

This also has no solution in the VS IDE. It offers no solution or idea of how to not be doing this.

I cannot find a way to turn this off in the `.editorconfig` file or the options within Visual Studio. Could someone help me with what I need to paste into the editorconfig file?

Comment: Haven't you found `dotnet_diagnostic.IDE2001.severity` or `dotnet_diagnostic.IDE2001.severity = true:error`?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue on VSCode using omnisharp; I've set `dotnet_diagnostic.IDE2001.severity = none` as the last line of my `.editorconfig` file but the warning still shows up.  
Have you found a way to fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the `true` from your `while`. It's the `{` at the end of the line.
I struggled with this, too. I could *not* disable it through the analyzer severits explicitly.

The only way I found to get rid of it is to lower the severity as one of the c# settings:
So instead of
`csharp_style_allow_embedded_statements_on_same_line_experimental = false:warning`
I had to change it to
`csharp_style_allow_embedded_statements_on_same_line_experimental = false`.

With that setting all of these diagnostics went away.